# Android Google Play Billing collect now pay later

Tags: react-native, stripe-payments, google-play-billing

In reference to [this from Google](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/9992660). I am developing an app in react native that I was going to use Stripe as the payment platform.

My requirements are:

- Collect billing details (i.e. credit card) but do not bill initially.
- back-end will bill periodically, but I need full control over the amounts (i.e. not a straight up subscription system)

Stripe allowed me to do just this. (My plan was to use a web view to direct user to a stripe checkout). I'm a bit unclear as to if Google Pay is the same as Google Plays Billing system.

Does Stripe have the ability to comply with this new policy from Google? If not does Google Play Billing allow this process (collect payment authorisation once, charge later)? Are their libraries for react native?

Answer (score 0):

Google Pay is different from Google "Play" Billing.

Google Pay is a digital wallet that securely stores your credit card details.

Google Play Billing is the in-app purchase mechanism for Android app users to pay for in-app content

What are your app's users going to be paying for?

If it is in app items, access to digital content (or any of the other things listed in https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/9992660) then you need to **not** use Stripe as a payment provider. Stripe would be used if the purchased items were physical goods (e.g. groceries).

I'm not sure what Google Play Billing capabilities are, you might have to reference their docs for that.

Comment: Thank you. The payment is for digital content.